# Entering login and pswd in new window

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am running a test on creating a movie and sharing it on facebook using selenium webdriver. I am stuck after the facebook login window opens. Can you tell me how I can enter the email and password inorder to complete my test. I am new to selenium

Comment: What is preventing you from doing this currently? Can you not access the input boxes? Are you unsure of how to enter text? Need clarification.

Comment: You need to locate the fields using their locators. Go through the below link and after getting yourself comfortable with using locators, you can easily start with your facebook project.
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check on internet.
Secondly, try some tricks before post a question like that.

So, you need to catch your input fields like :

```
WebElement inputName = driver.findElement(By.id("id of the input"));
inputName.sendKeys("freezer123@hotmail.com");

WebElement inputPassword = driver.findElement(By.id("id of the input"));
inputPassword.sendKeys("pass1234");

WebElement btnOk = driver.findElement(By.id("id of the button"));
btnOk.click();
```

Take a look [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)